# Pyomo + Bonmin solver: Number of iterations

Tags: python, pyomo

I use the Bonmin solver in Pyomo. When i set `tee=True`, and solve a model like this:

```
opt = SolverFactory('bonmin')
solver_message = opt.solve(model, tee=True)
```

Then I get the output:

Cbc0001I Search completed - best objective 41573.30169699511, took 11448 iterations and 220 nodes (18.05 seconds)

Cbc0032I Strong branching done 18 times (570 iterations), fathomed 0 nodes and fixed 0 variables

Cbc0035I Maximum depth 11, 0 variables fixed on reduced cost

Now, which variable saves this number of iterations (11448)? I suppose, it can be found somewhere in the `solver_message`?

Comment: Is it in `solver_message.iterations`?

Comment: Since I could not find a good documentation, I went in the PyCharm debug mode. `solver_message.iterations` does not exist, but there is `solver_message.solver.statistics.get('Black box').get('Number of iterations').value`. However, in my case it is not defined. But maybe there is a way to get the value set in there.